# Incompatible types in ternary conditional operator

Tags: java, generics, java-7, conditional-operator

I am trying to set a custom renderer for a drop-down box, based on a certain condition:

```
themeComboBox.setRenderer(
    settings == null ? themeComboBox.getRenderer() : new ThemeNameRenderer());
```

Where `themeComboBox` is an instance of `javax.swing.JComboBox<Path>`, and `ThemeNameRenderer` is a custom class that extends `DefaultListCellRenderer`.

This does not compile, with the following error

```
method setRenderer in class JComboBox<E> cannot be applied to given types;
    themeComboBox.setRenderer(settings == null ? themeComboBox.getRenderer() : new ThemeNameRenderer());
  required: ListCellRenderer<? super Path>
  found: ListCellRenderer<CAP#1>
  reason: actual argument ListCellRenderer<CAP#1> cannot be converted to ListCellRenderer<? super Path> by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
```

**How can I make this work with the conditional operator?**

---

- I cannot surround the call to `setRenderer` with an if-statement or similar, because I'm customizing the code through the NetBeans GUI editor. In fact, the entire reason I need to do this is that `ThemeNameRenderer` uses dependencies that shouldn't be loaded when designing the GUI in the editor.
- I am targeting Java 1.7. I think the code does compile on Java 1.8.
- I've found that the following code does work, but I would like to avoid the extra method if at all possible.

  ```
  themeComboBox.setRenderer(pickRenderer());

  private ListCellRenderer<? super Path> pickRenderer() {
      if (settings == null) {
          return themeComboBox.getRenderer();
      } else {
          return new ThemeNameRenderer();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: `themeComboBox.setRenderer((ListCellRenderer<? super Path>)
    ((settings == null) ? themeComboBox.getRenderer() : new ThemeNameRenderer()));` try type casting it

Comment: I think you have to cast the arguments to the appropriate type. Try `settings == null ? (ListCellRenderer<? super Path>) themeComboBox.getRenderer() : (ListCellRenderer<? super Path>) new ThemeNameRenderer());`. You may not need both casts.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande Ah, that's the key! I tried casting both arguments as Paul suggested, but not the entire thing.

Comment: ternary operator behaves unexpectedly in java sometimes. You can search for it, stackoverflow also has some questions on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they added some improvements to type inference in Java 8 and that might explain the difference in behavior.

Check the "Target Types" section in this page:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

> The notion of what is a target type has been expanded to include method arguments

This code compiles well for me using Java 1.7 (adding a cast is needed):

```
themeComboBox.setRenderer(
            (ListCellRenderer<? super Path>) (settings == null ? themeComboBox.getRenderer() : new ThemeNameRenderer()));
```

And your original code compiles well using Java 1.8:

```
themeComboBox.setRenderer(
            settings == null ? themeComboBox.getRenderer() : new ThemeNameRenderer());
```

Comment: You're right, that works! Do you know why it's necessary under Java 1.7?